# ¿Cómo abrir multiples archivos .sql en la misma instancia del SSMS v18.4?

Tags: sql, windows10, ssms, sql-server-management

Actualmente trabajo con múltiples archivos `.sql`, cada que le doy doble click al archivo me abre una nueva instancia de `SQL Server Management Studio`. Necesito que cuando haga doble click en el archivo se abra en la instancia del `SSMS` ya abierto.

Trabajo con `Windows 10 Pro` y `SQL Server Management Studio 18.4` (adjunto la ficha técnica de mi SSMS):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Como con todas las cosas de Microsoft, [la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726577/sql-management-studio-wont-open-scripts-on-double-click) a este horrible comportamiento por defecto (que tiene [al menos diez años](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-files-open-in-a-new-ssms-instance) de existencia) es... meterle la mano al registro (o arrastrar el script desde el explorador de windows a la ventana existente de SSMS, que suena más sencillo en el largo plazo).

Si prefieres que haga lo que debe al hacer doble clic, tienes que:

1. Ir al Editor de Registro, clave `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sqlwb.sql.9.0\Shell\Open\Command` (puede que la parte `sqlwb.sql.9.0` sea un poquitín diferente, yo tengo SSMS 18.7 y la clave a buscar es `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssms.sql.15.0\Shell\Open\Command`).
2. Editar el valor (Default)
3. Debe tener actualmente algo como: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde`
4. Añade un `"%1"` al final de ese valor
5. El valor editado debe ser algo como: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde "%1"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda que nada garantiza el que una actualización del SSMS no cambie esta clave a su valor original (o algún otro problema relacionado que pueda surgir). No es un solución a-prueba-de-balas en el tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve este mismo problema, descubrí que hay una solución simple
,solo verifica que el acceso directo de SSMS no está en la opción "Ejecutar este programa como administrador".En caso que este marcado, desactive la opción y ahora intente hacer doble clic en el archivo sql.

(haga clic con el botón derecho en el icono de acceso directo -> propiedad -> Compatibilidad -> Cambiar configuracion para todos los usuarios->Ejecutar este programa como administrador). En caso afirmativo, desactive la opción e intente hacer doble clic en el archivo sql.

Cuando se ejecuta como administrador abre una nueva instancia siempre que se ejecute un archivo query no se porque pero fue un dolor de cabeza solucionarlo
Espero les ayude saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]